# API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I can't make API requests with the Android Facebook SDK, or even get the user from the login callback - it always returns null.

Particularly, with the newMeRequest, I get the following error message:

```
{ "error": {
 "message": "API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument", 
 "type": "GraphMethodException", 
 "code": 100   } }
```

Actually, it seems pretty obvious, because the flag is set to true in the Facebook app options. However, I know it is possible, for the mobile sdks, to make API requests without the secret. However, if I try to use the access token from the `currentSession` in the Facebook Graph API Debugger, the response will be the same as above.

I don't know if this is related to the new Android Facebook SDK, but my code is basically the same as in the examples. The login goes nicely and I get the session token but I can't make any API requests...

```
loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
        graphUser = user;
    }
});


Request.newMeRequest(currentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    }
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

Comment: I am getting same error,How you resolved this.Please help me it's urgent.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The only way that I was able to put it working, was by settings to `No` the `App Secret proof for API calls` in the advanced settings of the facebook App.

However, this is a fix, not a solve, since I wasn't able to do the request in the option set to `Yes` (as is possible in the iOS facebook sdk).

Comment: is this safe? What are the security risks that come from disabling that opt?

Comment: @dwbrito This option is disabled by default. I think this option "enhanced" the security. This doesn't mean your FB app "unsafe" if you turn this option off.

Answer (score 18):

you need to add a parameter "appsecret_proof" to your request containg a 'sha256' hash of accessToken and appSecret

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Comment: Strangely it looks like this is the url now https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests%20/ I only say strangely, because not many urls have a %20 in them (other than that it's the same as your url)...

Answer (score 8):

You need to disable `Require App Secret` in facebook app advance settings.

Comment: is this safe? What are the security risks that come from disabling that opt?

Comment: Thank you so much. It is solved the issue. But Is it good as per the security aspects?

Answer (score 1):

While not an actual answer to your question (since it doesn't involve the Android SDK), it seems that, as of **March 2018**, there still are some issues regarding the **appsecret_proof** and calls from web page (Javascript) / and possibly mobile (not sure about that) clients.

[Facebook bug report (February 2018) - issue reappeared](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1597942793626594/)

[Facebook bug report (October 2016)](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1003618519783444/)

[Facebook bug report (February 2015)](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1379698435674774/)

That is, for an application with **Require App Secret** enabled `App Dashboard > Settings > Advanced > Security > Require App Secret`, it seems that one cannot perform API calls from Javascript without passing the `appsecret_proof` - at the moment of writing (March 2018).

Quick "fix" - disable the flag. Depending on the requirements, one may also choose to have two Facebook applications: one for web page / mobile calls (flag disabled), and one for server side calls (flag enabled).