# Aws Cognito - Facebook Sign Up, username attribute mapping required

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I created a cognito user-pool, Im using Google,Facebook as identity provider for sign up, Google works fine, but with Facebook i got an error.
Cognito generate Facebook;s button then the user login and allows share it information and email, but when aws Cognito recives the user's profile information don't create the user and return a error "userName mapping requiered" but on configuration I already mapped it, as the documentation especify.
[Error from Cognito](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmhMt.png)

[Facebook configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sJUi.png)

[Params mapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGTgv.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem caused by `App Secret proof for API calls` in the advanced settings of the Facebook App.
Set it to `No`.

Refer to the following link:
[API calls from the server require an appsecret_proof argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359611/api-calls-from-the-server-require-an-appsecret-proof-argument/22909841)